# How can i create 5 Processes using fork()?

Tags: c, process, operating-system, fork

I want to create 5 processes just like the picture shown i have tried a lil bit by printing out their pid's but its hard for me to visualize the fork() creating  them and get exactly what I want [The image shows 5 processes connected by pipes]

```
          P
       /     \
      M       M
      |        |
      C        C
```

Answer (score 3):

When you use `fork()` the `kernel` will create one new process and will return to the child (the new process) `0` and the `PID` to the parent. So, knowing this this is the following code to create the tree

```
if ((pid = fork()) == 0) {
    //I am process M1
    if (pid = form()) == 0) {
       //I am process C1
    } 
} else {
// I am still in P, so go on the next branch
    if ((pid = fork()) == 0) {
       //I am process M2
       if (pid = form()) == 0) {
          //I am process C2
       }
    }
}
```

Use `ps --forest` to visualize the process tree as in following example

```
~# ps --forest
    PID TTY          TIME CMD
   1295 pts/0    00:00:00 sudo
   1296 pts/0    00:00:00  \_ su
   1297 pts/0    00:00:01      \_ bash
   3541 pts/0    00:00:00          \_ ps
```

So you will see something like:

```
~# ps --forest
    PID TTY          TIME CMD
   1295 pts/0    00:00:00 a.out
   1296 pts/0    00:00:00  \_ a.out
   1297 pts/0    00:00:00      \_ a.out
   1298 pts/0    00:00:00  \_ a.out
   1299 pts/0    00:00:00      \_ a.out
```

Which will tell you if you have successfully made the tree.

Comment: i wanted to know about the fork process ,inside the c program

Comment: The `fork()` inside the program will create a process inside the `kernel`, so, visualize the processes to see the forks.

Comment: If you want to write a `C` code to draw the tree for the processes it had created, you need to start by the parent and build a tree as you call `fork()`

Comment: i wanted to ask if this creates the tree im looking for?

Comment: fork(){fork(){fork(){fork()}}};

Comment: how can i visualize this code which i have wriiten

Comment: check with `ps --forest` and you will get the tree.

Comment: hey but the given code above doesnt even go to else part ?so it just creates 3 processes right?

Comment: wrong, 4 `fork()` will give you 5 processes. Take the code, compile it and test it to see.